# Could you please help me out identifying the typeface (font)?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Could you please help me out identifying the typeface (font) used to design the logo presented below?

What about ornaments/emblems? Is there any font I could use to design similar style identification plate?

[image: AGAW. Logo]

Logo taken from http://agawphotography.blogspot.com/

Comment: Someone call the kerning police!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script is Bickham Script Pro, a face that ships with any of the Adobe Creative Suite apps, or is available directly from the [Adobe website](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1736). The sans is Myriad Pro Light Condensed. I would guess that whoever put this together is a Photoshop user, since both of these ship with Photoshop.

There are a bazillion ornaments like this on [iStockphoto](http://www.istockphoto.com).